# My mysqldump script keeps failing, says there's no preceding group in my.cnf

Tags: linux, mysql, mysqldump

So mysqldump throws the following error:

```
mysqldump: [ERROR] Found option without preceding group in config file /etc/mysql/my.cnf at line 22!
mysqldump: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!
```

My my.cnf is super basic:

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html 
#

# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
event-scheduler=ENABLED
```

Side questions: should I add something to my config file for extra security? And can I compress my tables somehow, preferably with phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two reasons why you might be seeing this:

### Reason 1

Your `my.cnf` file has not the `UTF-8` encoding. You can check that using the `od` command and seeing if there's something not in this encoding.

### Reason 2

You lack the `[mysqld]` directive at the top of your file. As I see it you don't have that option, so simply add it and try again.

> Side questions: should I add something to my config file for extra security?

Usually running your MySQL to only listen to `127.0.0.1` is a good practice, since it allows connections only from your local machine. The rest of security options are based on the permissions you grant to your databases, tables, etc.

> And can I compress my tables somehow, preferably with phpmyadmin?

InnoDB allows compression. See the [reference manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-compression.html) for more info.

Comment: Thanks. Adding [mysqld] fixed the issue.